# How to stop Dropdown menu from going up when minimized?

Tags: html, css, css-float

When ever i minimize the browser window, the drop down menu goes up and goes left, how to correct it?

Here's the css code:

```
div#secondary-menu {    bottom: -62px; position: relative;    z-index: 5;   text-align:center; margin:auto; width:100%;}

    ul#secondary {    display: inline-block;    font-size: 13px;    padding: 0 !important; }
    ul#secondary li { padding-right: 12px; }
    ul#secondary li a { color:#fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #105059; padding: 6px 0px 13px 9px; }
    ul#secondary li a:hover {text-decoration: none; color:#eeeeee;}
    ul#secondary ul { background: url(images/secondary-dropdown-bg-blue.png) no-repeat bottom left; border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; padding: 8px 0px 17px 15px; width: 173px; box-shadow: 3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); -moz-box-shadow:3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); z-index: 200; }

#secondary li:hover ul, #secondary li.sfHover ul { top:39px; }
#secondary ul li:hover ul, #secondary ul li.sfHover ul { top:-8px; }
ul#secondary > li { background: url(images/secondary-menu-linkbg-blue.png) no-repeat left bottom; }             ul#secondary > li.sf-ul.sfHover { background: url(images/secondary-menu-linkbg-blue.png) no-repeat bottom right;  }     ul#secondary > li.sf-ul.sfHover > a { background: url(images/secondary-menu-linkbg-blue.png) no-repeat top left; display: block; color: #000000; text-shadow: none; color: #ffffff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #737373;}
ul#secondary ul li a { background: url(images/secondary-dropdown-bullet.png) no-repeat 0px 12px; padding: 5px 3px 5px 15px; text-align:left; width:155px; font-size: 90%; }
ul#secondary ul li a:hover { color: #8eaeb1; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #0b454e; }
```

Here the link to site:

http://demo.nextsyntax.com/goldcoast/

Regards

Comment: can you share a screen-shot for your issue, what I have found in you provided link is the drop-down menu opening in the behind the slider.

Comment: Yes. But if you try to minimize the browser window the menu goes up.

Comment: sorry not getting your issue :(

Comment: What you want to do to this, make it responsive??

Comment: Yes! I want to make it responsive.

Comment: I've corrected the issue of drop-down menu opening behind the slider through 

z-index: 5;